# python: генерация вариантов слагаемых суммы с помощью itertools (или иных библиотек)

Tags: python, python-3.x, производительность, комбинаторика

Подскажите как быстро решить следующую задачу:

есть сумма `S` и `n` слагаемых, причём первое и последнее слагаемые могут быть равными 0, а все остальные слагаемые только больше 0 (от 1 и выше)

необходимо сформировать все возможные варианты

например для `S = 2` и `n = 3` будут такие варианты:

```
0 1 1
0 2 0
1 1 0
```

создал такой код:

```
# вычислить варианты
def calculate_variants(variants, variant, s, n_max, n):
    if n == 1:
        variants.append(variant + [s])
    else:
        for i in range(0 if n == n_max else 1, s + 1):
            calculate_variants(variants, variant + [i], s - i, n_max, n - 1)

# получить варианты
def get_variants(size, data):
    variants = []
    calculate_variants(variants, [], s, n, n)
    return variants
```

код конечно немного кривоватый, но рабочий

но хотелось бы более производительный алгоритм

подскажите можно ли это как то с помощью библиотек типа itertools сделать, чтоб и код был покрасивше :) и попроизводительнее

Comment: Опять же - в каких пределах возможны `S` и `n`? )

Comment: @CrazyElf - условно небольших - S - [..100] n - [100]

Comment: Вам нужны все варианты одновременно в виде двумерного списка, или подойдёт их перебор в единственном 1D списке?

Comment: @MBo, мне нужно по заданному S и n получить одномерный список

Comment: Видимо, я как-то не так задал вопрос. Один вариант - один список. Все варианты - много списков, в вашем коде они объединены в список списков variants, и выдаются все скопом. Но построение всего этого требует постоянного перераспределения памяти (`variant + [i]`). А если список длиной n завести единожды, в нём гонять единицы направо-налево, и выдавать варианты (на проверку или для чего они нужны) по очереди, то должно быть быстрее.

Comment: @MBo, да, тогда именно так- 1 список - это один вариант слагаемых, например (0, 2, 0), а все возможные варианты для заданного `s` и `n` - это список списков, например [(0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (1, 1, 0)] - вот именно этот список списков и хочется получить с максимальной производительностью

Comment: Нулевые граничные значения не надо проверять каждый раз. Задача сводится к поиску перестановок для `n=X`; для `n=X-1` добавляя к результату 0 слева или справа; для `n=X-2` и добавлению 0 с обоих сторон. `itertools` может помочь только перестановками. Если вы сгенерировали последовательность `(1,1,2)` для `n=3` и `s=4`, то `set(permutations('112', 3))` выдаст все ее варианты.

Comment: @Lecron, а можно чуть-чуть подробнее про граничные значения - не совсем понял

Comment: Порядок генерации важен?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, нет, поскольку все это превращается потом в битовую запист

Comment: Есть идеи как получить быструю генерацию. Мне нужен комплект пар `(s, n)` для тестирования.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, простой пример (50, 7) - свыше полумиллиона вариантов, вычисляется за 0.25 сек, но надо хотя бы на порядок быстрее (ну или иначе надо думать о другом подходе в алгоритме)

Comment: `(50, 7)` -> `18009460` (`= Cnk(51, 6)`) вариантов. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: числа не оттуда привел так что всё делаете так :), я привел С(26, 7), поскольку там есть еще накладные расходы, так что ориентироваться можно как на (50, 7) так и на (26, 7) (что как раз даёт 0,25 сек)

Comment: Очень интересная задача. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Рекурсивная генерация с `numpy`. `numpy` экономит память и очень быстро работает при копировании частей таблицы (нужно для заполнения и кеширования). Таблица с комбинациями выделяется один раз в начале работы. В кеше хранятся указатели на куски таблицы. Сам массив `cache` требует очень мало памяти. `order='F'` улучшает скорость копирования кешированных кусков в три раза.

```
def variants(s, n):
    result = np.zeros((math.comb(s + 1, n - 1), n), dtype=np.uint8, order='F')
    cache = [[None] * n for _ in range(s + 1)]

    def v_range(s, i):
        if i == 0:
            return 0, s - (n - 2) + 1
        if i == n - 1:
            return s, s + 1
        return 1, s - (n - i - 2) + 1

    def fill(p, s, i):
        if i == n:
            return p + 1

        if cache[s][i] is None:
            q = p
            for v in range(*v_range(s, i)):
                qq = fill(q, s - v, i + 1)
                result[q:qq, i] = v
                q = qq
            cache[s][i] = p, q
            return q

        cp, cq = cache[s][i]
        q = p + (cq - cp)
        result[p:q, i:n] = result[cp:cq, i:n]
        return q

    q = fill(0, s, 0)
    assert q == result.shape[0]
    return result
```

> ```
>  s n        число      время
>        комбинаций     работы
>
> 26 7       296010     0.0035
> 50 7     18009460     0.0672
> 97 7   1052618392     3.5804
> ```

Последний результат требует около 7Gb. Отдельного кеша нет - оптимальный результат.

**P.S.** Это легко переносится на C++. Интересно, кто будет быстрее: Python или C++?

Comment: Скорее всего С++. Если не использовать jit-компиляцию. А там уже кто знает.=)

Answer (score 2):

Основное время занимает организация хранения - ведь вариантов очень много, их число растёт экспоненциально. Если вместо принта активировать елд, то время работы без сохранения (а варианты при этом генерируются) и с сохранением результатов в двумерный список (`v = [x for x in compo(6, 3)]`) отличается раз в 30.

Поэтому, если есть возможность -  обработать вариант и забыть про него. Если всё надо сохранять в файл - возможно, запись каждого варианта по очереди даст какой-то выигрыш.

Код этот адаптирован из [моего ответа на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279508/844416), там же приводится сравнение с компилируемыми языками.

Генерируется комбинация из `n` чисел, в сумме дающих `s-(n-2)`, затем к средним элементам добавляются единицы

```
def compo(n, s):
    x = [0] * n
    s = s - n + 2
    x[0] = s
    adder = [1] * n
    adder[0] = 0
    adder[-1] = 0

    while True:
        print([a+b for a,b in zip(x,adder)])
        #yield([a+b for a,b in zip(x,adder)])
        v = x[-1]
        if (s==v ):
            break
        x[-1] = 0
        j = -2
        while (0==x[j]):
            j -= 1
        x[j] -= 1
        x[j+1] = 1 + v
```

Comment: да, принцип понял, надо будет подумать, потому что пока вроде как требуются все варианты сразу (там их несколько миллионов)

Answer (score 2):

Наверное оно

```
from itertools import product

def compo(n, s):
    return [x for x in product(range(s+1), repeat=n) if sum(x) == s and 0 not in x[1:-1]]
```

На выходе будет список кортежей. С ними уже делайте, что нужно.

Comment: Это значительно медленнее чем то что уже есть у автора вопроса.

Comment: ну это да, зато покрасивше и с itertools )

Answer (score 2):

Не быстрый вариант, но как источник возможных идей:

```
def variants(s, n):
    for c in itertools.combinations(range(s + 1), n - 1):
        yield np.diff((0, ) + c + (s, ))


for c in variants(4, 3):
    print(*c)
```

> ```
> 0 1 3
> 0 2 2
> 0 3 1
> 0 4 0
> 1 1 2
> 1 2 1
> 1 3 0
> 2 1 1
> 2 2 0
> 3 1 0
> ```